# Optimize IQueryable query to let EF generate a single SQL query instead multiple. Child collection of an entity must contains a custom collection

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core, query-optimization

The goal is to have a single query that will be generated by the EF and MSSQL will execute it in one go. Having the current implementation, everything works correctly, but not optimal. To be more specific, looking at the SQL Server Profiler logs, it makes additional `exec sp_executesql` queries per each company to fetch data (in example below, it would be `Products`).

Say, we have selected product ids.

```
List<int> selectedProductIds = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

We filter over a collection of `Companies` to get only those companies that have **ALL** selected products.

And a query where we dynamically extend it as many as we need, thankfully to `IQueryable` interface.

Imagine `x` of type `Company` and it contains a collection of `Products`.

```
if (selectedProductIds.Count > 0)
{
    query = query.Where(x => selectedProductIds.All(id => x.Products.Select(p => p.ProductId).Contains(id)));
}
```

Is there any way to rewrite the predicate using LINQ? I know I can make a dynamic SQL query myself anytime, but I am trying to understand what I miss in terms of EF/LINQ. Thanks!

The version of Entity Framework Core is 2.1.

**UPD:**
Company products are unique and never duplicated within a company entity. No need to make distinct.

Comment: What version of EF Core are you using?

Comment: @GuruStron The version is 2.1.

Comment: @GuruStron this way it would not guarantee that a company has absolutely all selected products (`selectedProductIds`), so `.Any()` looks wrong.

Comment: 2.1 by default executed in memory parts of queries it was not able to translate. In this case I would try to write manual join.

Comment: @GuruStron yeah I know, this is why I am thinking if there is any way to rewrite my small predicate that EF can understand and generate a query automatically. It is not a big deal for me to construct a query manually, it is more "professional" interest whether EF/LINQ can do so at all.

Comment: By "manual" I meant using `Join` from LINQ. As for predicate - I would try to look at either generating needed expression via expression trees or maybe LINQKit has something for such situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following query:

```cs
if (selectedProductIds.Count > 0)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Products
        .Where(p => selectedProductIds.Contains(p.ProductId))
        .Count() == selectedProductIds.Count
    );
}
```

Comment: This is what works fine in a such case as mine. The EF generates an efficient `AND EXISTS (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...correlated query by id.. + IN ()` and then a vital check for counts to make sure that all selected items exist in a company. Thanks, Svyat.